# Why is bytes[] a nested array?

Tags: solidity, remix, evm

Using `bytes[] foo` as a function argument

```
contract b {

function c(bytes[] foo) {

}

}
```

in https://remix.ethereum.org gives error

```
UnimplementedFeatureError: Nested arrays not yet implemented.
```

Why?

Answer (score 2):

`bytes` on its own is already a dynamically sized byte array.

Adding an additional `[]` makes it a dynamically sized array of dynamically sized byte arrays.

Please refer to the manual:

http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/types.html#dynamically-sized-byte-array