# Assembly for array with bytes64, to bypass nested array error

Tags: solidity, contract-development, evm, assembly

Since it is not possible to pass call code with an array of bytes64, as an array with types bigger than `bytes32` becomes a nested array, [Why is bytes[] a nested array?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/29798/why-is-bytes-a-nested-array)

How would assembly be used to pass call code with an array of bytes64?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `bytes` which is for variable length byte arrays.

Comment: Yes I could pass 64 byte signatures in a sequence with `bytes`, how would assembly be used to loop through and extract the 64 byte sigs?